# Why can't I get the foot and the ankle move with the rest of the leg?

Tags: bones

I have parented and connected the bones of the armature:
[image]

Yet, when I move the upper leg, the toe and the ankle don't follow.
[image]

And I when I go to Pose Mode, the ankle move but I can't apply IK to the toe:
[image]
What can I do to get the toe and the ankle to move with the upper leg without deforming in Pose Mode?

My .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: Yes. Thanks indeed. But how do I upload the file to this page?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Don't forget to paste the link here ;)

Comment: Sorry. First time.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2603" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2603/)

Comment: Let me review it in a little while. And how I vote on the answer and accept it. I want to give credit where credit is deserved. I just need to know how.

Comment: One last thing. This means that I can download the same file with the adjustments from the same link I pasted before?

Comment: No, you can update your file (the one provided in the link you sent) by following what I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Okay. How do I give you credit for your answer?

Comment: you can do this as shown here http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=111593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are setting lots of IK constraints. To fix this I disabled the IK constraints for all bones except for the `leg.lower_L.001` bone. To disable the IK you click on the eye icon as shown below:

[image]

Then I select the `leg.lower_L.001` bone and set the chain length of its IK constraint to 3 to affect the whole leg (it's 3 parents) and now the IK works great as shown below:

[image]

To move the bones in edit mode, you will need to select the whole bones and move them together as shown:

[image]

Comment: Two last questions: 1) How I can get the two legs to move independently? 2) How can I get the legs to bend at the knee in Pose Mode?

Comment: @BlackMiti could you please ask another question on the website and I'll check it and provide an answer? cause it may be helpful for other people who has the same issues. Once you do it send me the link here and I'll answer it.