# How to bend legs at the knee and make them move independently?

Tags: bones

Follow up to: [Why can't I get the foot and the ankle move with the rest of the leg?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71948/why-cant-i-get-the-foot-and-the-ankle-move-with-the-rest-of-the-leg?noredirect=1)

1) How I can get the two legs to move independently? 2) How can I get the legs to bend at the knee in Pose Mode?

Thanks Tak

Comment: I just did. And thanks again. One last question though. Why is the knee bending in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the two legs move independently you need to go into edit mode and turn the x-mirror off as shown below:

[image]

To control knee bending, you need to add a new bone for pole targeting as shown here:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21385/2517